# Accents and emojis are not sent when creating new templates in the content template builder

Tags: node.js

When creating new templates in the content template builder, accents and emojis that are registered are not being sent. Templates created previously work normally. For example, the template 'dev_auth_sso_es' functions properly. However, templates created after it, such as 'dev_auth_sso_pt', already exhibit the issue.

Some templates created yesterday worked, but today we are unable to create functional templates.

Comment: Which template library are you using? You may need to set the `charset` for example `<meta charset="UTF-8">`